# c# how to connect multiple clients to a TcpListener

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener, connection

I am implementing a game in a WPF application. I need to connect at least 10 players to a server. I have always worked with only one `TcpClient` and one `TcpListener`. Is there any way to connect a lot of clients to a server? I tried to create one thread per connection, but did not work. I have searched and I couldn`t find a simple example that could teach me how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

If you scroll to the bottom there are other available examples, such as a TCP chat server/client which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339782/how-do-i-get-tcplistener-to-accept-multiple-connections-and-work-with-each-one-i) for explanation provided by Jon Skeet, which seems to be more concise than the link provided above.