# Network port listener on c#

Tags: c#, http, system.net

I'm trying to listen the active ports on my network. I tried HttpListener, but I'm not sure if this is the right listener. Any ideas or examples?

```
using (m_listener = new HttpListener())
{ 
m_listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/"); 
m_listener.Start(); 
while (m_listener.IsListening)
{ 
HttpListenerContext context = m_listener.GetContext(); 
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request; 
HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response; 
textBox1.Text += request.RawUrl + "\r\n"; 
textBox1.Text += request.UserHostName + "\r\n"; } 
m_listener.Stop(); 
}
```

Comment: show some code please... elaborate on what you really want to achieve...

Comment: using (m_listener = new HttpListener())
   {
    m_listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
    m_listener.Start();
    while (m_listener.IsListening)
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = m_listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        textBox1.Text += request.RawUrl + "\r\n";
        textBox1.Text += request.UserHostName + "\r\n";
    }
    m_listener.Stop();
   }

Comment: and what is it you want to achieve ? build a web server (that's what HttpListener is for) ? what problems do you see / error messages / exceptions ?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745401/tcplistener-is-queuing-connections-faster-than-i-can-clear-them can provide some guidance .

Comment: I need to scan the request my network is doing

Comment: sorry I don't understand... are you trying to build a webserver ? or are you trying to build something like WireShark ? or a proxy server ? or a portscanner ?

Answer (score 2):

HttpListener is probably not your best bet if you want to do a full network scan. I would look into the System.Net.Sockets namespace. Port scanners are typically done via the sockets interface. You can create TCP and UDP sockets and bind them to listen to any port on a local machine or connect to a remote machine. If the socket succeeds, then the port is open and ready.